# Portals is not working in Unity 2D using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am make a 2D game and i am trying to make portals in the game. But portal does not work when player try to get in the portal it collides with the portal and bounces off..
This is my Portals scripts.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Portal : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Transform destintion;

    public bool isOrange;
    public float distance = 0.2f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (isOrange == false)
        {
           destintion = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("orangePortal").GetComponent<Transform>(); 
        }
        else
        {
            destintion = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("purplePortal").GetComponent<Transform>();
        }       
        
        /// <summary>
        /// sent when another object enters a trigger collider attached to this 
        /// object (2d physics only).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name = "other"> the other Collider involes in this collision.</param> 

            void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, other.transform.position) > distance)
            {
                other.transform.position = new Vector3 (destintion.position.x, destintion.position.y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your portal Collider2D component there must be a tick named `Is Trigger`. When it is enabled your collider will no longer collide but becomes a region that detects other collliders that enter in it.

You need your player to have `RigidBody2D` and `Collider2D` components like this:

[image]

Then you need two portals set with `Collider2D` component added and `Is Trigger` enabled:
[image]

And third you need your portals to have the teleporting script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PortalTeleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private PortalTeleport destinationPortal;

    private HashSet<Collider2D> ignoredArrivals = new();

    protected void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D enteredCollider)
    {
        if (ignoredArrivals.Contains(enteredCollider)) { return; }
        destinationPortal.TeleportObject(enteredCollider);
    }

    protected void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        ignoredArrivals.Remove(collider);
    }

    public void TeleportObject(Collider2D teleported)
    {
        teleported.transform.position = this.transform.position;
        ignoredArrivals.Add(teleported);
    }
}
```

The `destinationPortal` is where in the inspector you assign the (other) portal that the object should arrive at. The purpose of `ignoredArrivals` collection is to prevent a gameObject that just appeared through the portal to be teleported back again - when something arrives at the portal it is ignored until it moves away from the portal.

Comment: Thanks for answering can explain in more dept

Comment: @Obscure021 sure why not but i can't vote my reputation is 11 and it has to be minimum 15.

Comment: I think accepting is not limited by rep.

Comment: @Nikaas Thanks now it start working. Sorry but can you highlight my mistake in the above script that why it was not working. Your answer helped me alot.

Comment: It was not specifically the script. Look at the first sentence in the answer - `Is Trigger` tick makes a collider into pass-through trigger region.